# Which dependency should be added in pom file to import org.apache.tiles.controller?

Tags: java, jsp, maven-2, jsf

Which dependency should be added in pom file to import `org.apache.tiles.controller`?

Comment: It's funny how similar "Pom" and "Porn" look in the SO font...

Answer (score 1):

org.apache.struts.tiles.Controller is an interface in Struts Tiles 1.x, which you can find in the maven artifact "org.apache.struts:struts-tiles"

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
    <artifactId>struts-tiles</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.10</version>
</dependency>
```

Keep in mind, this only works with Struts 1.x, and not Struts 2.

http://struts.apache.org/1.x/struts-tiles/

Comment: @Andrew :I am using jsf and not struts.Do you know dependency for tiles in jsf?

Comment: @Warrior, sorry I haven't used JSF and it's been a long time since I used tiles either. I've found SiteMesh to be far easier to use on straight JSP sites (although it could be different for JSF)

Answer (score 0):

According to https://tiles.apache.org/download.html#Tiles_3_as_a_Maven_dependency :

```xml
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
  <artifactId>tiles-extras</artifactId>
  <version>3.0.5</version>
</dependency>
```